# Lasagne - error

Tags: python, theano, lasagne

i am trying to learn neural nets / lasagne by using the code in Robert Layton's Learning Data Mining with Python. I think i am following the code to the letter, but i get the following error message. any hints or intuition what i am doing wrong much appreciated;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-78-3ff2950373de>", line 3, in <module>
    updates=lasagne.updates.sgd(loss,all_params,learning_rate=0.01)

  File "C:\Users\WouterD\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\lasagne\updates.py", line 134, in sgd
    grads = get_or_compute_grads(loss_or_grads, params)

  File "C:\Users\WouterD\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\lasagne\updates.py", line 110, in get_or_compute_grads
    return theano.grad(loss_or_grads, params)

  File "C:\Users\WouterD\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gradient.py", line 551, in grad
    handle_disconnected(elem)

  File "C:\Users\WouterD\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\theano\gradient.py", line 538, in handle_disconnected
    raise DisconnectedInputError(message)

DisconnectedInputError: grad method was asked to compute the gradient with respect to a variable that is not part of the computational graph of the cost, or is used only by a non-differentiable operator: W
Backtrace when the node is created:
  File "C:\Users\WouterD\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\theano-0.7.0-py2.7.egg\theano\compile\sharedvalue.py", line 248, in shared
    utils.add_tag_trace(var)
```

code below:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris=load_iris()
X=iris.data.astype(np.float32)
y_true=iris.data.astype(np.int32)

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y_true,random_state=14)

import lasagne
input_layer=lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(10,X.shape[1]))

hidden_layer=lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(input_layer,num_units=12,nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.sigmoid)

output_layer=lasagne.layers.DenseLayer(hidden_layer,num_units=3,nonlinearity=lasagne.nonlinearities.softmax)

import theano.tensor as T
net_input=T.matrix('net_input')
net_output=output_layer.get_output_for(net_input)
true_output=T.ivector("true_output")

loss=T.mean(T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(net_output,true_output))
all_params=lasagne.layers.get_all_params(output_layer)
updates=lasagne.updates.sgd(loss,all_params,learning_rate=0.01)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not computing the loss with respect to the real input variable. `net_input=T.matrix('net_input')` is your own symbolic input to the network but Lasagne had already created one for you when you created the `InputLayer`. You also don't need to get the output with respect to a particular input, just get the output with respect to the input layer.

So, replace the two lines

```
net_input=T.matrix('net_input')
net_output=output_layer.get_output_for(net_input)
```

with the single line

```
net_output=lasagne.layers.get_output(output_layer)
```

Anticipating the next issue you'll have, you can get the input variable Lasagne created for you via `input_layer.input_var` so you can compile your training function like this:

```
import theano
f = theano.function([input_layer.input_var, true_output], outputs=loss, updates=updates)
```

Answer (score -1):

`input_layer=lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(10,X.shape[1]),input_var=input)`

while the input is the tensor you defined before